# npm pre/post hook with wildcard match

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Let's say I have the following scripts in my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "release:public": "....",
     "release:beta": "...."
  }
}
```

But now I want to add a `prerelease` script that is identical for both `release:public` and `release:beta`. Is that possible to have a `prerelease:*` or another way to runs before both scripts?

Comment: You can make a script that calls the other two... I'm not 100% what you're looking for

Comment: You'll need to do something like [this example](https://paste.ee/p/vS5ty). Essentially add `npm run prerelease && ....` before each existing `release:public` and `release:beta` script. I'd consider also renaming the `prerelease` script to e.g. `beforerelease` to avoid any potential undesired results if a npm script named `release` also exists is _package.json_.

Comment: I found myself in a need of the same functionality. I have many scripts starting with 'generate...' and I would love to be able to add a single hook for each of them. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I do understand your question and the example from RobC is usable, but the naming was not recommended. When you use pre in a script command name followed by a command name that also exists. The part wil run before (previous) the other (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#npm-run-user-defined)

```
{
 ...
  "scripts": {
    "beforerelease": "....",
    "release:public": "npm run beforerelease && ....",
    "release:beta": "npm run beforerelease &&  ...."
  },
  ...
}
```

But that is an even amount of work then using the pre-tag functionality like this

```
    {
 ...
  "scripts": {
    "prerelease:public": "....",
    "release:public": "....",
    "prerelease:beta": "....",
    "release:beta": "...."
  },
  ...
}
```

Like Kousha probably has, i have a package with a lot of different run scripts. And i want to use one script that runs before a lot of the others. So the question is still standing: Is it possible in any way to use wildcards in de command part of a script tag in a package.json?